# OpenGL - reconstruct position from depth in VS

Tags: opengl, glsl, projection

I am trying to reconstruct position from depth texture in Vertex Shader. Usually, this is done in Pixel Shader, but for some reason I need it in VS to transform some geometry.

So my approach.

1) I calculate View Frustrum corners in View Space
I use this input NDC.Those values are transformed via Inverse(view * proj) to put them into World Space and then transformed via view matrix.

```
//GL - Left Handed - need to "swap" front and back Z coordinate
MyMath::Vector4 cornersVector4[] = 
{
    //front
    MyMath::Vector4(-1, -1, 1, 1), //A
    MyMath::Vector4( 1, -1, 1, 1), //B
    MyMath::Vector4( 1,  1, 1, 1), //C      
    MyMath::Vector4(-1,  1, 1, 1), //D

    //back
    MyMath::Vector4(-1, -1, -1, 1), //E
    MyMath::Vector4( 1, -1, -1, 1), //F
    MyMath::Vector4( 1,  1, -1, 1), //G     
    MyMath::Vector4(-1,  1, -1, 1), //H     
};
```

If I print debug output, it seems correct (camera pos is at dist zNear from near plane and far is far enough)

2) post values to shader

3) In shader I do this:

```
  vec3 _cornerPos0 = cornerPos0.xyz * mat3(viewInv);
  vec3 _cornerPos1 = cornerPos1.xyz * mat3(viewInv);
  vec3 _cornerPos2 = cornerPos2.xyz * mat3(viewInv);
  vec3 _cornerPos3 = cornerPos3.xyz * mat3(viewInv);

  float x = (TEXCOORD1.x / 100.0); //TEXCOORD1.x = <0, 100>
  float y = (TEXCOORD1.y / 100.0); //TEXCOORD1.y = <0, 100>

  vec3 ray = mix(mix(_cornerPos0, _cornerPos1, x),
         mix(_cornerPos2, _cornerPos3, x),
                 y);


  float depth = texture2D(depthTexture, vec2(x, y));
  //depth is created in draw pass before with depth = vertexViewPos.z / farClipPlane;

  vec3 reconstructed_posWS = camPos + (depth * ray);
```

But if I do this nad translate my geometry from `[0,0,0]` to `reconstructed_posWS`, only part of screen is covered. What can be incorrect ?

*PS: some calculations are useless (transform to space and after that transform back), but speed is not concern atm.*